# Changing a number in a string of numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, variable

I'm trying to write a function that will let me change a number in a list of numbers based on a position. For example, I want to be able to change the fourth number in the list `10.90.123.80.42` to `19` so that I get `10.90.123.19.42`.

I'm wanting something along the lines of:

```
NUMBERLIST=10.90.123.80.42
changeNumberByPosition "$NUMBERLIST" "4" "19"
echo $NUMBERLIST

10.90.123.19.42
```

Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm fairly new to scripting and any help I could get would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide some kind of formula. What you want is in generally feasible, but depend of the input and output

Comment: You should think about whether it is required to have some kind of error handling. It easy to write something like `function changeNumberByPosition { echo $1 | sed "s/\([0-9]*\)/$3/$2"; }`, but it will be painful to debug this when there won't be enough arguments to the function or the position is not a number. If this could ever happen I would strongly recommend to include code to check the arguments and give meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Using awk:

```
function changeNumberByPosition { 
  echo | string=$1 position=$2 newvalue=$3 \
    awk -v FS=. -v OFS=.  '{ 
      $0=ENVIRON["string"]; 
      $ENVIRON["position"]=ENVIRON["newvalue"]; 
      print;
   }';
}
```

Sample run:

```
NUMBERLIST=10.90.123.80.42
new=$(changeNumberByPosition "$NUMBERLIST" 4 19)
echo "$new"
10.90.123.19.42
```

or to update the existing value with a new value:

```
NUMBERLIST=10.90.123.80.42
NUMBERLIST=$(changeNumberByPosition "$NUMBERLIST" 4 19)
echo "$NUMBERLIST"
10.90.123.19.42
```

### Using bash v4+:

```
function changeNumberByPosition ( 
  set -o noglob
  IFS=. 
  a=($1); 
  a[$2]=$3;
  printf '%s\n' "${a[*]}" 
)
```

The bash-only version of the function:

1. splits the first parameter (e.g. $NUMBERLIST) into an array `a`, based on periods, using IFS.
2. replaces the `$2` parameter with the value in `$3`.
3. prints the first N-1 elements of the array, each followed by a period, then prints the last element of the array.
4. it does all this in a subshell, so that `$a` doesn't clobber the existing environment.

Comment: replaced -v's with ENVIRON; I don't like the `echo | awk ...` but I don't know of a better way

Comment: See [Slurp-mode in awk?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/304457). But here using your `echo` approach makes more sense IMO.

Comment: No need for twice `IFS=.` Note that it's now compatible with `ksh93`, `mksh` and `zsh` in sh/ksh emulation (though  if the last component is empty it only works properly in the latter).

Comment: right! I'll leave it broken out, for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`:

```
NUMBERLIST=10.90.123.80.42
typeset -T NUMBERLIST numberlist . # tie $NUMBERLIST variable to $numberlist array
                                   # in a similar fashion as $PATH is tied to
                                   # $path, but here using "." instead of ":" as
                                   # the separator
numberlist[4]=19
printf '%s\n' $NUMBERLIST # with updated 4th field.
```

You can also do the splitting and joining manually with:

```
NUMBERLIST=10.90.123.80.42
list=("${(@s:.:)NUMBERLIST}")
list[4]=19
NUMBERLIST=${(j:.:)list}
printf '%s\n' $NUMBERLIST
```